# Resizing an Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

If this were a regular array, I could just create a new array and then do arraycopy, but generics won't let me do that. The best thing I've come up with so far is:

```
public void resize() {
    T[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray,myArray.length*3);
}
```

It compiles, but at run time, I get a null pointer exception. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason `java.util.ArrayList` doesn't work for you? It kind of handles all this and more, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you are resizing arrays, you probably want a generic ArrayList.

Comment: I'm familiar with Arrays and ArrayLists, but I'm just trying to learn about generics. Thanks for the suggestion (In practice, ArrayList is what I would probably use).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `Arrays.copyOf(myArray,myArray.length*3)` to make the copy

my guess is that `myArray[0]` is null so `myArray[0].getClass()` throws the nullpointer

if you need the runtime type of the components you can use [`myArray.getClass().getComponentType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you're getting a null pointer on the first line of `resize()` it's probably because you have no value in `myArray[0]`. If that is null, your `getClass()` will bomb.
2. You don't appear to be assigning `myArray = tempArray` so you'll probably run into an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds soon.

Comment: That was it, I tried manually adding some stuff to the array and that fixed it, so the problem is elsewhere. And good catch on #2, sorry I forgot to paste that into the question.