# Copy arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have a little problem with this:

```
 private void resize(int i) {                         
   this.capacity +=i;                           // new capacity
   this.memoryaux = new Integer[this.capacity]; // create array aux with new capacity
   for (int a = 0; a < this.capacity; a++)
     this.memoryaux[a] = null;                  // initialize null
   this.memory = this.memoryaux;                // copy array aux into my array             
 }
```

I want to resize the array memory that has for example a capity of 2. But it already has inside something, so i'm trying to create a new array (`memoryaux`) with the new capacity, and then copy the new in the old one.

My problem is that i lose everything in the old array, how can i do it without loosing everything inside? An example would be like this:

Old array with capacity 2 has [0]1 [1]2.

create new array with a bigger capacity of 4.

Then change the capacity of the old array and it finish like this: [0]1 [1]2 [2]null [3]null

Comment: Why not use ArrayList?

Comment: Try with `arraycopy` function: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: This is not memory but array size.   Lots of existing questions and answers around this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313628/resizing-an-array

Comment: go and have a look at ArrayList source file, and have a look at method  `ensureCapacity`, you can find there some ideas

Comment: Can you remove the Eclipse tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [public static  T[] Arrays.copyOf(T[] original,int newLength)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5b%5d,%20int%29).

You need to specify a new length that is greater than the old length. This will copy your existing array into a new larger array.

```
// Intializing an array of length 3
int[] array = new int[] {45, 32, 75};
// Copying array with newlength as 5
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, 5);
array[3] = 11;
array[4] = 55;
```

or - in Java before 1.6 [public static void System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
// Intializing an array of length 3
int[] array = new int[] {45, 32, 75};
// Copying array with newlength as 5
int[] biggerArray = new int[5];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, biggerArray, 0, array.length);
biggerArray [3] = 11;
biggerArray [4] = 55;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong

```
this.memory = this.memoryaux;  //copy array aux into my array
```

This is not copying! this is override. Your original data from memory array is lost.

Answer (score 0):

you are re assigning the old-array-reference-variable to point to the `new-array-object` with the bigger size, which means that the reference to the `old-array-object` is lost and may be garbage collected

what you have to do is to copy the contents of the `old-array-object` to new array object before you assign to the `old-array-reference`

To copy the array : you can do something like this:

```
class ArrayCopyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
                'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
        char[] copyTo = new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, you never copy the existing values into `memoryaux`. You're just assigning `null`s to all indexes in the auxiliary array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should need to append one your `memory` array to `memoryaux` array then try to copy to `memory` array. tgThat will resolve this issue.

```
private void resize(int i) {                         
   this.capacity +=i;                           // new capacity
   this.memoryaux = new Integer[this.capacity + this.memory.length]; // create array aux with new capacity
   for (int a = 0; a < this.memory.length; a++)
     this.memoryaux[a] = this.memory[a];                  // initialize null
   for (int a = 0; a < this.capacity; a++)
     this.memoryaux[this.memory.length + a] = null;                  // initialize null
   this.memory = this.memoryaux;                // copy array aux into my array             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the method may be renamed increaseSize(int i).

The issue is that you forgot to copy the values of the old array in the new one. In the last line, this.memory is affected the address of the new array but nothing more so the old array and its content is lost.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the old array to a new one (before `this.memory = this.memoryaux;`:

```
System.arrayCopy(this.memory, 0, this.memoryAux, 0, this.memory.length);
```

Don't initialize the new array elements to null... this is already done by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

public class Tool {
    int capacity = 2;
    int[] memory = new int[capacity];

```
private void resize(int i) {                         
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(memory));
    this.capacity +=i; 
    int temp [] = memory;
    memory = new int[capacity];
    for(int k = 0; k<temp.length; k++){
        memory[k] = temp[k];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(memory));
} 
public static void main(String[] a){
     new Tool().resize(8);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.copyOf` to resize the Array.

Let's start an example first:

```
Integer[] dataArray = new Integer[10];
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        dataArray[i] = i;
    }

    //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
    System.out.printf("Old capacity ==> %s \n", Arrays.toString(dataArray));


    int oldCapacity = dataArray.length;

    //newCapacity = 2 * oldCapacity
        int newCapacity = oldCapacity <<1;

    //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] 
    dataArray = Arrays.copyOf(dataArray, newCapacity);

    System.out.printf("New capacity ==> %s \n", Arrays.toString(dataArray));
```

With the above example, **one-line code** can implement the `resize` method, like,

```
 private void resize(int i) {                         
       this.memory = Arrays.copyOf( this.memory, capacity+i);
     }
```